# does not work parcing scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

It does not collect data from the title. I made in the sample, but it still refuses to work.Here is my code:

toster.py:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from toster.items import DjangoItem

class DjangoSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "django"
allowed_domains = ["www.toster.ru"]
start_urls = [
'http://www.toster.ru/tag/django/questions',
]

rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=['/tag/django/questions\?page=\d']),
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True)
]


def parse_item(self, response):

    selector_list = response.css('div.thing')

    for selector in selector_list:
        item = DjangoItem()
        item['title'] = selector.xpath('div/h2/a/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code:

- remove `www.` from the `allowed_domains`
- fix your regular expression inside the Link Extractor - replace `\d`  with `\d+`
- set `unique=False` to let Scrapy handle the pagination pages
- fix your extracting logic in `parse_item()` - for instance, there are no elements with `thing` class on these pages

Fixed version (works for me):

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from toster.items import DjangoItem


class DjangoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "django"
    allowed_domains = ["toster.ru"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.toster.ru/tag/django/questions',
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['/tag/django/questions\?page=\d+'], unique=False),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True,)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        selector_list = response.css('div.question__content')

        for selector in selector_list:
            item = DjangoItem()
            item['title'] = selector.css('a.question__title-link[itemprop=url]::text').extract_first().strip()

            yield item
```

Comment: why outputs \u041a\u0430\u043a \u0434\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432 ?

Comment: @AlekseiM this is a separate problem. The code already fixed what you've asked about and more.